# adding event listener for keydown to react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add an event listener for `keydown` event in an image (or div) tag. It works if I add it to the document with `document.addEventListener`, but it doesn't when I try to put it into the specific element that I create in react (I noted in the code what works and what doesn't). Also `handleClick` works and `handleKey` does not, no matter which format I put it into the tag with.

```
class PrescriptionImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      patient: "",
      rotation: 0
    };
    this.handleKey = this.handleKey.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({rotation: this.state.rotation + 270})
  }

  handleKey(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
      if (e.ctrlKey) {
        this.setState({rotation: this.state.rotation + 270})
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
//    document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKey, true); This doesn't work (no error)
//    this.RxImage.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKey, false); This doesn't work, (can't find addEventListener of "undefined")
//    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKey, false); This works.
    fetch("http://localhost:3333/patientAddress.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            patient: result.order.patient
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKey, false);
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, patient, rotation } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return <img className="prescription-image" style={{width: "98%", height: "98%", transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`}} src={"data:image/png;base64," + patient.rx.imageData} onClick={() => this.handleClick()} onKeyDown={this.handleKey} />;
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PrescriptionImage />, document.getElementById("left"));
```

Comment: The event is called `onKeyDown` (camelcase). Try renaming your prop: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

Comment: Weird, I copied that from stackoverflow something. Changing it to the correct case didn't change anything (no error, doesn't work), going to change it in the question

Comment: try adding a ref to the img or div:
ref={ (el) => {this.handleKey = el }} then in handleKey(e) 
'if e.key === <key_code>

Comment: Tried ref in the 2nd commented line there.... gives me this error: ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`.... If I leave the line commented out I get no error, doesn't work. (I had previously added ref={(RxImage) => {this.RxImage = this}}, but your version also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

**You got 2 main issues here:**

1. The `keyDown` event needs the `div` to be in focus. one way to do it
   is to add a `tabindex` attribute to the `div`. after you focus on it
   you can trigger the `onKeyDown` event on any key on the keyboard.
2. In your handler you are trying to check for `e.code` but in fact the
   correct property is `e.keycode`.
   with that said, you should carefully [read about the browsers support for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) as it is considered as deprecated at some browsers.
   [Here is a list of the available properties of this event and their status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) (check `key` for example).

**EDIT**
I have added another approach, using the [ref API of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
This way you can attach an event listener the way you did before and also trigger a focus via code (see `componentDidMount`).

Here is a running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myDiv.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
    this.myDiv.focus();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.myDiv.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
  }

  handleKey = e => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={this.handleKey}>click me</div>
        <div tabIndex="1" ref={ref => this.myDiv = ref}>by ref</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I checked the event object and code actually had the right string set (it works if i document.addEventListener).

Comment: yeah as i mentioned you need to focus on the element in order for it to work. you can do it with the mouse or tab etc. as for the `code` property you are using, that is strange i don't see it in the list. i would stick to the supported and official properties. check the links i attached.

Comment: @xyious I've added another example using ref. this way you can trigger a focus with code.

Comment: Funny thing, I can't actually make your code work. I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

I'm using babel-core 5.8.23, tried with your react version.

Comment: are you calling it inside a native react life-cycle method or your own?  if its your own method handler, don't forget to bind it to the class instance

Answer (score 1):

This implementation worked well for me.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myDiv = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myDiv.current.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
    this.myDiv.current.focus();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.myDiv.current.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
  }

  handleKey = e => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div tabIndex="0" onKeyDown={this.handleKey}>click me</div>
        <div tabIndex="1" ref={this.myDiv}>by ref</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```